# How to get time wise Record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need Time Wise Sales Report in mysql,I get the Report like

```
Time    Amount
19:00:00    2
20:00:00    5
21:00:00    0
22:00:00    0
23:00:00    14
```

but I need sum of Amount like

```
Time    Amount
19:00:00    2
20:00:00    5
21:00:00    5
22:00:00    5
23:00:00    14
```

This is  my Query

```
SELECT concat(MID(date_of_call, 12, 2),':00:00') TimeIntervel,COUNT(*) TotalEntries,date_format(date_of_call,'%d/%m/%Y') FROM ICC_MM_setup_suply 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_of_call,'%d/%m/%Y')='31/01/2017'
GROUP BY concat(MID(date_of_call, 12, 2),':00:00')
```

Comment: If you could live with `WHERE date_of_call ='2017-01-31'` it would potentiality be much faster

Comment: why does the data set have zeros anyway? (It's confusing because the result doesn't correspond with the query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use User variables:

```
set @lastval := 0;    
select
    time,
    @lastval := if(Amount = 0, @lastval, Amount) Amount
from t
order by time;
```